# Remove input element from cell and preserve the value, when clicked outside of cell or another cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want input elements in cells to disappear when I click outside of cells or on another cell (note that clicked cell must be active afterwards, have an input element). 
And cell must keep value of input element.

When cell is clicked, input element must appear (that part is solved).

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//this part creates input in td element, allows editing cell content and 
//when enter is pressed removes input leaving the cell value (the okay part)
    $("td").click(function(){
        if($(this).find("input").length==0){
            var cellContent = $(this).html();
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
            $(this).find("input").focus();
        }
        var currentCell = $(this);  

        $("input").keyup(function(event){
            if(event.which == 13){//on enter pressed
                $(this).remove();
                $(currentCell).html($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
```

**Now the problem:**

```
//Here every cell but the one clicked should behave just like the cell in
// which "enter" is pressed in previous part of the code 
//I was trying smth here but I (amateur) got confused
$("*").click(function(){
   for(var i=0;i<$("td input").length;i++){
     if($(this).has("input")){
        var cellValue = $("td input:eq("+ i +")").val();
        var address = $("td input:eq("+ 0 +")").parent();
        $("td input:eq("+ i +")").remove();
        $(address).html(cellValue);
     }    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, how I would do it: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6ug0pe3/)

Hope it helps.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.visible {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var tds = $('td');

tds.click(function(){

    var allInputs = tds.find('input');
    var clickedInpit = $(this).find('input');

    if (allInputs.hasClass('visible')) {

        allInputs.removeClass('visible');
        allInputs.addClass('hidden');
    }

    clickedInpit.addClass('visible');
    clickedInpit.removeClass('hidden');
});
```